# store procedure parameter SAP Crystal Report jsp

Tags: jsp, crystal-reports

I have two kind of parameter, static parameter and parameter from store procedure, I already done for show the static parameter in report. but when I send the parameter from jsp to crystal report, in this case store procedure parameter, it failed.

I send parameter with:

```
parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "V_PANGKAT",
                V_PANGKAT);
```

V_PANGKAT is store procedure parameter. is it posible set the value parameter from jsp and show the dynamic reports based on the parameter input? how to fix this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

declare a variable in the procedure for the "V_PANGKAT" value. send the value of the V_PANGKAT through the procedure to generate the crystal report and use your UI to select the value of V_PANGKAT from user.